# R shiny Modals, DT datatables and responsive elements not working after clean install Rstudio and R

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog, dt

I am working on an app on my old PC but sometimes I work from my laptop. After getting a new laptop I installed the newest version of R, Rstudio and all the packages needed to run the app. The app itself is running (no errors, no warnings), however Modals and DT dataframes are not shown, and UI reactivity (like updateSelectInput) and rendering normal dataframes (without DT) does not seem to work on the new laptop. I installed Java, rJava and shinyjs since some of the packages and components use Java or Javascript. The app works fine on the old PC. On 2 different laptops, the same happens, no interactivity or rendering of DT tables and Modals (checked in different browsers with js allowed).

Downgrading the shiny package does not seem to work (1.7.5 to 1.7.4). I double checked the documentation for DT datatables and Modals, nothing seems to have changed that would alter the functioning of these packages in the way I have used them.

Some examples of parts of the code (variable names are generalized in examples).

Modal:

```
observeEvent(input$uploadData, {
  showModal(
    modalDialog(
      size = "l",
      title = "Upload data",
      easyClose = FALSE,
      fileInput(
        inputId = "Files",
        label = "File:",
        accept = c(".csv", ".xlsx", ".xls"),
        multiple = TRUE
      ),            
      footer = tagList(
        modalButton("Cancel"),
        actionButton(
          inputId = "addData",
          label = "Add Data")
      )
    )
  )
})
```

DT datatable UI (using DToutput did not change anything):

```
                  fluidRow(
                    DT::dataTableOutput("Data"),
                    style = "overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: scroll;"
                  )
```

DT datatable server side:

```
DataTable  <- reactiveVal(dfData) 

output$Data <- DT::renderDT({
      data.table(DataTable())
    })
```

Since I normal UI interaction and normal dataframe rendering do both not work, I suspect that there is a general problem, however I have no idea where to start looking.

Old PC: Windows 11

- R version: 4.2.2
- Shiny version: 1.7.4

Other PCs: Windows 10 or 11

- R version: 4.3.1
- Shiny version: 1.7.5

Does someone have an idea what could be the problem here?

Many thanks in advance!

EDIT: I found actually nothing is running within the server part (print function does not work inside server part of the app). Using print before the app is defined does work, but afterwards, it gives an error that app.R does not return a shiny.appobj object.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the issue. I use the package bs4Dash. The newest version of this package (2.3.0) seems to create an error in the browser (Uncought error: cannot call methods on tooltip prior to initialization).

Going back to the previous version (2.2.1) fixed the issue!